# store a simple string as text file in azure synapse (to data lake gen2)

Tags: python, azure, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to do store a simple string as a text file in datalakeGen2 with python code written in synapse notebook. But it doesn't seems to be straight forward.

I tried to convert the text into rdd and then store:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]"))
str = "test string"

text_path = adls_path + 'test.xml'

rdd_text = sc.parallelize(list(str)).collect()
# type(rdd_text)

rdd_text.saveAsTextFile(text_path)
```

but it gives out error as:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'saveAsTextFile'
Traceback (most recent call last):

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'saveAsTextFile'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
As `python rdd_text = sc.parallelize(list(str)).collect()`  so here, you are results are stored in the form of list in the `rdd_text`. As it a normal python statement because `collect()` returns a list.

RDD is a distributed data structure and basic abstraction in spark, which is immutable.

For eg,  `remove()` or `append()` are the objects of lists in python so as to add or remove element -as such save `saveAsTextFile` is the object of RDD to write the file.

As in the below picture you can see `tuple()` has no attribute as append because they are immutable so are RDD.
[image]

Hence, instead of `python rdd_text = sc.parallelize(list(str)).collect()`  could use `python rdd_text = sc.parallelize(list(str))`  so it wont store the result as a List.

```css
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]"))

string = "test string"
adls_path="abfss://data@xxxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/symbolexcel.xlsx"

text_path = adls_path  + 'test.xlsx'
rdd_text = sc.parallelize(list(string))

rdd_text.saveAsTextFile(text_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out! I teste the code that you answer, and it stores the text as several blob files, and the file name that I have given to it became the folder's name. Are there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Here is the document which can be followed to achieve the files in one partition as we have to use `write()`: https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/output-one-file-csv-parquet/,  for the renaming the folder : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101135/how-do-i-rename-the-file-that-was-saved-on-a-datalake-in-azure

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with pandas.  You will need a linked service to connect synapse to the storage location.  [Using Pandas in Synapse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/tutorial-use-pandas-spark-pool) see also [Pandas to txt](https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-write-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-txt-file/)

import pandas as pd

string = 'test_string'

path = adls_path + 'test.txt'

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [string]})

df.to_csv(path, sep='\t', index=False, header=False)