# How to save 15k csv files in databricks/ Azure data lake

Tags: python, csv, data-science, databricks, azure-databricks

I've a question how should I download a .csv files from Auzre data lake then make some calculation and save this in .csv again.
I know that for downloading .csv I can use: `data=pd.read_csv('example.csv') #example`

`new_data=data//2+data #calculation in databricks notebook`
and now the question is how to save `new_data` in .csv format  in Azure Data lake with the name: `example_calulated.csv`

Comment: Question language is unclear. Please modify the language and code format of your question so other can better understand what problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

To access files from ADLS you need to Mount an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 filesystem to DBFS.

To read files from ADLS use the code below.

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").option("delimiter",",").load(file_location)
```

After applying transformations on data, you can write data in CSV file. Follow below code.

```
target_folder_path = 'path_to_adls_folder '

 
#write as CSV data

df.write.format("CSV").save("example_calulated.csv ")
```

Then you will have to rename saved csv file using dbutils.fs.mv

Although it rather copies and deletes the old file. There is no real rename function for Databricks

```
dbutils.fs.mv(old_name, new_name)
```

To rename 15K files you can refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54191522) answered by sri sivani charan